# Angular 6 Route with path '**'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

Hi I am new to angular I have a doubt, like I saw a route with { path: '**', redirectTo: ''} why do we use and in which situation. Thanks

Comment: Handle 404 i guess

Comment: Handles unspecified routes

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration):

> The ** path in the last route is a wildcard. The router will select
>   this route if the requested URL doesn't match any paths for routes
>   defined earlier in the configuration. This is useful for displaying a
>   "404 - Not Found" page or redirecting to another route.

Where the routes looks like the following:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'crisis-center',
    component: CrisisListComponent
  },
  // Other routes
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
  }
];
```